# Update query matching records but not updating table

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset that I'm trying to debug a few issues on, and I've run into a case where an update query matches a record in the table, but doesn't update the data. This is my dataset:

```
> describe genotypes;
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id           | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| userstamp    | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| timestamp    | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)


> SELECT id, userstamp FROM genotypes WHERE id = 7276;
+------+-----------+
| id   | userstamp |
+------+-----------+
| 7276 |      NULL |
+------+-----------+
```

When I try to run my query to update the userstamp field, I get the following result:

```
> UPDATE genotypes SET userstamp = 142 WHERE id = 7276;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I've remove all my triggers from the table, so I'm not sure what's blocking the update.

Comment: Maybe you have no auto commit?

Comment: Do you commit your updates after executing your query ?

Comment: Since when do you need to run an extra command to commit queries? I'm not running my queries in a transaction.

Comment: Did you update Mysql recently? what version are you using?

Comment: try use UPDATE genotypes SET 'userstamp' = '142' WHERE 'id' = '7276'

Comment: @haytem I'm running MySQL 5.7.10.